# Add a Sign in portlet on the login page

Tags: authentication, modal-dialog, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am building a basic login page using the existing sign-in portlet.

I just want to have a functionality that when a user access the website, right now localhost:8080, the sign-in portlet should pop up!

Is this doable? If so, Can someone please hint me how this can be done?

---

This is how the default page looks like right now:

[image: Default page]

To log in, I have to explicitely click on the "sign-in" blue button and then it pops out a modal sign in portlet.

[image: pop-up sign-in portlet]

***But what I am trying to do here is:***

1. Whenever a user clicks on the default url, it should immediately ask the user to login rather than showing a blank page with a sign-in button (something like the output image)
2. Or even a modal sign-in box (Whatever is easy to customize.)
   *and*
3. Whenever a user hits any other url for eg. `localhost:8080/web/project1/home` and if the user is not signed in, it should force him to sign in first.

[image: home page with sign-in portlet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities out of the box:

- place nothing but the sign in portlet on the homepage, appearing at that location (typically /web/guest/home)
- protect your default page to be not visible to the guest user (this will automatically forward to the sign-in portlet) - see the "Permissions" button on the "Manage Pages" interface

There are more, but these seem to be the first and most obvious ones. Let me know if one of them works for you or what the reason for your request is

Comment: Hi @olaf, The sign in portlet is already added to the main page/home page (/web/guest/home)... While trying to add again to the homepage, it doesn't allow me to add it.

Comment: I don't understand - If it's already there, why do you want to add it again?

Comment: Umm.. i'll just edit the question with images. I hope that will make it clear.

Comment: so, did you try any of my suggestions? Which didn't work for you and why?

Comment: Hi @Olaf, Yes i did! 
- For the first option you mentioned, my default page already contains the sign-in portlet, so when I try to 'Add' a sign-in portlet, the option is greyed out. It doesnt' allow me to add it.  
- For the second option, when i disabled view access of the default page to all users, it broke! Now i get a message - 'The website has a redirect loop'!

Comment: Ok... so now, I created a new public page (web/guest/login) and in portal-ext.properties gave `auth.login.url=/web/guest/login`. This is now my default page when user types `localhost:8080`. Works as expected! +1 to you for your help.

Comment: I have one last question here though. Now I have a login page(`web/guest/login`) and a landing page after login (set by `default.landing.page.path=/web/games/home`). My question is - When a user is logged in successfully and types localhost:8080, it takes him to the login page again! Is there any setting/property we can set to make sure if a user is logged and then types in localhost:8080, he is redirected to web/games/home rather than web/guest/login?

Comment: if this answers your questions please accept it as an answer instead of upvoting. Regarding the second question in this comment thread you can open a new question and users can answer it there. But just to lighten your curiosity a little, you may get your hands dirty with filters or may be use custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want the Login Portlet to popup as a modal window/lightbox on the **current page** (i.e. without leaving the page). AFAIK, to achieve this, you'll have to develop all your portlets to use AJAX to create links that point protected resources. So when you get an unauthenticated request, you can stay on the same page and show login dialog.

This is high-level approach. You'll need to 1) embed the Login portlet in your theme and 2) put the below javascript functionality in Theme:

- callback function - to handle response for unauthenticated request,
- to render modal/lightbox

You might face surprises while implementing this.